# reload UITableView in UINib which is in an UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm, uinib

The title sounds a bit more confuesing as it is.

I have an `UITableView` where I instantiate a `UINib` which holds a `UITableView`.
This TableView lets call it "DetailTableView" displays some information which can be added in another ViewController - so far so good.

What I want to achieve is that this "DetailTableView" automatically updates after I added a new entry.

The entry is saved in a local Realm database and is already displayed correctly but the "DetailTableView" only updates when I force close and reopen the app.

I already tried to reload the `UINib` and fire a `tableview.reloadData()` with Notification which posts in `viewWillAppear()` but I can't get that thing to work. 
I also tried to fire `instatiate:WithOwner` or `awakeFromNib()` but that didn't worked as well.

I have searched through the web a lot and also on here but cant find any answer I hope you guys can help me.
thanks a lot!

Comment: you need to use realm notification for that here https://realm.io/blog/realm-objc-swift-2-4/

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code

```
data = try? realm.objects(Model.self)

token = data?.observe { (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in

                switch changes {
                case .initial:
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    break
                case .update:
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    break
                case let .error(error):
                    fatalError("\(error)")
                    break
                }
            }
```

Comment: the original tableView where you can add entries is updating fine the problem is, that I have another ViewController where there is a UINib and in this UINib there is a tableView populated with the same data but filtered and this tableView in the UINib does not update - only if I reopen the app

Comment: as it is a UINib I have done it like this: 

if let listView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ListView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? Listview {
            listView.tableview.reloadData()
        }

But either this nor other thinks like: 

listView.newNew.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)
            listView.todoView.setNeedsDisplay()
            listView.todoView.setNeedsLayout()
            listView.awakeFromNib()

...worked.